# Vim: alignment of public keyword

Tags: c++, vim, d

Currently, vim aligns my `public:`s like so:

```
class foo {
  public:
     void bar();
}
```

Which is to say, 2 spaces before `public:` and then a full tab (which is three spaces in my case) after it.

How would I get it to align thus:

```
class foo {
 public:
   void bar();
}
```

As in the `void bar();` is indented at exactly one tab (three spaces), and the `public:` is sort of "halfway" (or one spaces in)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++ indention defaults to `cindent` and as such can be tweaked by setting `cinoptions`. To get the indention you ask for, do this:

```
set cinoptions+=g1,h2
```

See `:help cino-g` and `:help cino-h`.

As mentioned in the comments `cino-g` and `h` do not always work, an alternative is `:help cinoptions-values` which leads to the same list. `:help indent.txt` is also useful.

Comment: `:help cino-g` doesn't work for me (neither the `-h`). `:help cinoptions-values` comes close though.

Comment: Is your `vim` compiled with `cindent`? `vim --version | grep '+cindent'`.

Comment: I'm using gVim 7.3 with '+cindent', and `:h cino-g` also doesn't works here. It seems that it is not a help keyword. There is no such keyword marker at online help either: [cinoptions-values](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html#cinoptions-values), and `helpgrep cino-g` returns 'no match'.

Comment: @thor, yes it is. I _do_ use cindent. Anyway, `cinoptions-values` explains everything (and it's very interesting, thanks).

Comment: That's odd, I'm using pre-compiled vim in Debian version 7.3 patchlevel 429. `cinoptions-values` leads close to the same place,  so that's useful if the others do not work, I'll add it as an alternative, thanks.

Comment: Just to confirm, vim applies the same rules in regards to indenting to D as it does to C/C++?

Comment: Just checked and it is the same. The indention files for 7.3 are in  `/usr/share/vim/vim73/indent/`, `c.vim`, `cpp.vim` and `d.vim` respectively.